# how to use angularjs template for a kendo ui grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, angularjs-templates

I am trying to use a kendo ui controls with angularjs. Most examples i have seen use kendo templates instead of angular templates to define a grid should look.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible; Check this demo - http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/angular